# Determining cumulative distribution function when given expectation and variance

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, variance

I am working on the problem of finding the cumulative distribution function of a variable $X$, which can take values $-1$, $0$, or $1$, has expectation $0.1$, and variance $0.89$.

I don't understand how to go about this problem, as all the examples I can find online go the other way. From what I understand, I need to find three separate probabilities, one for each value $X$ can take, which should add up to $1$, correct? How do I go about doing this?

Comment: If $P(X = -1) = a$, $P(X=0) = b$, and $P(X+1)=c$, what can you say about $a$, $b$, and $c$?  You know that they have to sum to 1, and you know what the mean and variance must be.  This gives you three equations (one for each of the sum, mean, and variance) in three unknowns ($a$, $b$, and $c$).  You might try solving this system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is the right approach.  If you let the probabilities of $-1,0,1$ be $a,b,c$ you have three equations in three unknowns.  One is $a+b+c=1$ because the sum of the probabilities has to be $1$.  One comes from the expectation, which is $(-1)a+(0)b+(1)c=0.1$.  The third comes from the variance.  Write the variance in terms of $a,b,c$ and solve the equations simultaneously.

Comment: Thank you! In order to write the variance in terms of a, b, c, would I start with the Var[X] = E[X^2] - E[X]^2 equation and write both of those terms in terms of a, b, c?

Comment: Yes, that is one way.  The other is to use the definition of the variance, but they amount to the same thing.  You know $E[X]=0.1$ so you are halfway there.

Comment: Two quick questions: how do a, b, c play into the definition of variance? Would I substitute them in for each xi? And for giving my final answer, is cumulative distribution function just a piecewise function where I see it's equal to a if x = -1, etc.?

Comment: You compute $E[X^2]$ from $a,b,c$.  Your final cdf will be a piecewise function.  It is $0$ for $x \lt -1, a$ for $-1 \le x \lt 0, a+b$ for $0 \le x \lt 1$ and $1$ for $x \ge 1$.  I think I got the equal signs in the right places, but you should check.